# Synchronizing TWO select elements - BOTH visual and modular - Problem

Tags: javascript, html, synchronization

I'm a total beginner and I'm sorry if the question is formulated wrong or just plain dumb.

I need to sync two dropdown select fields, but at the moment the synchronization is only visual, and the function (appearing button after a value is selected) of the second dropdown "box2" is not working.

The function of the second dropdown is a button

It only works when I select it manually.

Any help is really appreciated :)

```
<select id="box1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="box2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>


function sync(el1, el2) {
  if (!el1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(el2).options[el1.selectedIndex].selected = true;
  }
}

var selectToSync = document.getElementById('box1');
selectToSync.onchange = function() {
  sync(this, 'box2');
};
```

P.P the help I got so far:

"You're not writing it in the model, only in the visual field, and you're removing its binding, so that's why its not working"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like this. You will notice a few things:

1. I used addEventListener which allows you to listen to an event.
2. e.target is the element that triggered the event.

```js
var box1El = document.getElementById("box1");
var box2El = document.getElementById("box2");

function sync(el1, el2) {
  if (!el1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(el2).options[el1.selectedIndex].selected = true;
  }
}

box1El.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  sync(e.target, "box2");
});

box2El.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  sync(e.target, "box1");
});
```

```html
<select id="box1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="box2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I've tryed your code, but the sync only became two sided, now each dropdown can sync the other, but I guess the onchange function of the second dropdown is not working.